# Device Driver function behavior on interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, rtos, freertos

Suppose an embedded system is running FreeRTOS and an application program makes calls to a device driver interface (let us assume I2C). What exactly happens when this is interrupted by an external interrupt? In addition, how much sense does it make to implement the driver functions as tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly happens when this is interrupted by an external interrupt?

How interrupts are handled depends on the system. But a driver is just like any other code, it will stop execution temporarily in favour of the interrupt.

> In addition, how much sense does it make to implement the driver functions as tasks?

A properly written driver consists of two modules: a hardware abstraction layer which is what your application calls, and the actual driver, which is system-specific and non-portable.

Ideally the driver should be completely free of any application-specific things, so it makes no sense to put a driver in an OS task. A driver is/should be much lower level than things like operative systems. You could however put all the application code communicating with a certain driver in a task of its own. For example a protocol encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 1):

A device driver (for devices like I2C) is typically split into an application interface and a hardware interface.

The application interface typically just puts the data you want to send to the device in a buffer, and notifies the hardware interface part of the driver that there is data to send, and then returns to the caller. Asking for data would involve checking if there is enough data already available and either waiting for the data to become available or returning it immediately.

The hardware section of the interface would take data in the write buffer and pass it to the hardware as fast as the hardware can accept it - hardware typically notifies the driver, by an interrupt to say that it either has received data to process, or it can accept more data to transmit.

There is a requirement that the hardware and application sections do not attempt to modify the shared storage buffers at the same time, and there are several ways this can be achieved.

Using interrupts is optimal, because the processor only has to do work on servicing the hardware when the hardware indicates that it is ready. To do the same thing in tasks involves a process known as 'polling' essentially asking the hardware if it is ready. You could think of this as being analogous to turning off your telephone ringer, and picking up the phone periodically to see if someone is calling.

Comment: "Using interrupts is optimal" Well that's quite an over-simplification. It depends on your specification and how the program should behave. If you have a surgeon who aborts a critical moment in the middle of operation just to pick up their ringing cell phone, they are doing a much worse job than the surgeon who shuts off their phone and only checks it after the operation is done. Asynchronous interrupts are in fact very problematic for lots of different reasons and are therefore usually avoided in mission-critical applications.